# What shell command can I use to switch keyboard layout (language)? I have 2: us, ru. Lubuntu, lxqt

Tags: lubuntu, lxqt

I want to create script that would change language to "next". If it was us, it will be ru, if it was ru, it will be us.

I could not find option to create such shortcut because I don't know how to change keyboard layout via shell script/command in Lubuntu + lxqt.